# why can't I connect to mysql with uwamp,

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

`/* Please input your sql-connection correctly`

```
Made by Nitti
*/

$sqlHost = 'localhost';
$sqlUser = 'root';
$sqlPass = '';

// Please don't change anything below
mysql_connect($sqlHost, $sqlUser, $sqlPass) or die('Could not connect to the mysqlserver ('.mysql_error().')');

mysql_select_db('db_nit')
;
```

and as a result

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\UwAmp\www\admin\php\connectDb.php on line 13

I'm using `

> Apache 2.2.24 (with SSL)
>   MySQL 5.6.11
>   PHP (5.3.25 / 5.4.15) with Xdebug 2.2.0
>   PHPMyAdmin 4.0.2

`

Comment: At a guess I'd say your PHP hasn't got the mysql extensions included. Create a one-line page like this: <?php phpinfo(); ?>, and browse it. It will tell you what extensions you have (amongst other things). Look for mysql, mysqli and PDO.

Comment: @MikeW beat me to it :)

Comment: PS: I highly recommend Xampp for Windows, it comes with PHP 5.5.3 and MySQL/MySQLi/PDO enabled, as well as other cool things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_*` functions were deprecated and will then removed from PHP. You need to use the `mysqli_*` functions or PDO for database operations now.

See PDO manual: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

See mysqli manual: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: While they are deprecated, they are not yet removed from PHP.

Comment: mysql_* functions haven't been removed from PHP yet, and certainly not from PHP 5.3 or 5.4

Comment: @RonLugge According to https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation `mysql_*` gets E_DEPRECATED errors in 5.6, but not removed.

Comment: PHP 5.6 is not out. The OP is using MySQL 5.6 and PHP 5.3.25 / 5.4.15.

Answer (score 1):

Default UwAmp MySQL password is "root".

```
$sqlHost = 'localhost';
$sqlUser = 'root';
$sqlPass = 'root';
```

Answer (score 0):

Using mysql_connect has been depreciated for a long time. At a guess, they finally got rid of the feature entirely in your version, given that you're receiving an undefined function error.

As another poster also added, you should use either mysqli_* functions, or better yet the PDO library.  I *strongly* recommend the PDO library, but the mysqli library does work as well.

The PDO library will give you the advantage of making your database object oriented *and* properly abstract away the actual database, giving you the freedom to eventually move onto other databases if the program requires.  It might look like a little bit of work to learn, but it's much easier than you think once you dig into it and really start using it.

Comment: 5.6? He's using PHP 5.3 and 5.4, and mysql_connect isn't even deprecated in those releases.

Comment: @MikeW yeah, I was distracted and read the mysql version instead of the PHP version.  Oop.s

Comment: $sqlHost = 'localhost';
    $sqlUser = 'root';
    $sqlPass = '';
    
    // Please don't change anything below
    $conn = new mysqli($sqlHost, $sqlUser, $sqlPass, 'db_nit');
    
    if ($conn->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
    }

this is my current code

and as a result 

> Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in C:\UwAmp\www\admin\php\connectDb.php on line 13

Comment: @ArijanitNittiSalihu please don't post long code snippets in comments, they're impossible to read and wind up burying your actual text.  From the looks of it, whatever version of PHP you're using (custom compiled?) doesn't have database support.  Not sure why.